# chrome add block software that lets non intrusive adds run

Tags: chrome

I hate audible adds, and any adds that run in javascript and slow down my computer.  However, I also want to reward sights that provide me with free content by providing them with add revenue whenever possible.

Therefore I'm looking to block only the most annoying of adds.  Anything that tries to play audible content, perhaps anything that runs so much javascript in the background as to kill my computer performance (and I have seen adds like that).  I would like to leave all non-invasive adds running for all websites.  Ideally I would also like to allow any adds that run prior to video's on sights like hulu, youtube, etc as I feel that is a situation where they are justified in running audible adds.

Can anyone suggest a chrome, or firefox, extension that can easily be configured to *only* block invasive adds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well ABP or ublock let's you choose your adblock lists.

ABP does that, including their [acceptable-ads policy](https://adblockplus.org/acceptable-ads), which demands certain non-intrusive-ness. It is however also hotly debated, because [money comes into play](http://www.businessinsider.de/criteo-pays-adblock-plus-to-appear-on-its-acceptable-ads-whitelist-2015-12?r=US&IR=T)...

If you stick with ublock (similar, but without this questionable policy), you could still start with no ad-block subscription lists, and then [manually define on your own block selectors](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8916449), what annoys you... (also see [here](http://www.extremetech.com/internet/214151-ad-blocking-for-the-masses-part-one-ublock-origin))

---

Alternatively (or in my opinion: additionally): [Ghostery](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/ghostery/) has pretty fine-grained blocking options, you could try to [only block a few advertising networks, hoping to catch the right ones](https://uwnthesis.wordpress.com/2012/12/13/ghostery-how-to-configure-ghostery-to-stop-trackers/).

Personally, I'd block'em all.